# Avoid Crash Minidump while using Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm using Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin v4.9.5 on QGIS 2.14.3.
OS is Windows7 64 bit.

After I conduct some analysis by Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin, it is always shown "Crash minidump".

Would you tell me how to avoid this?

I've checked "QGIS 2.14. minidump crash when closing program" and so far.
Uninstall the QGIS and remove .qgis2 folder.
And reinstall QGIS and Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin.

But the message is still shown.

Regards,
Akihiko

Comment: I was advised that it is the matter of QGIS not Plugin.
So, I'll report this issue to QGIS community.
But if you have some information about this, I'm waiting for some suggestion.

---Add one more information---
I'm going to use this software on Win7 Enterprise 64 bit in Japanese.
I'm wondering this issue is just because of the language settings, so I tried to adjust this again, run on English, but it didn't fix that.

Comment: Additonal Information

Comment: Additonal Information.  I also tested this by QGIS 32 bit on Win7 32 bit Japanese version. When I created an AOI as a training data, the software always quit...I suppose it is better that I use QGIS 64bit on Win7 64 bit. Because I can get the classification result.

Comment: Any news on this issue? I'm trying to use the plugin on my system and have the same problem. Is there any way to avoid QGIS to crash when using it?